# Publish Silverstripe site to a subdomain

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

This is my first site built in Silverstripe, I have been developing the site locally (localhost) which has been working well, today I'm trying to publish it to a subdomain eg subdomain.mainsite.com.

I moved all the code and database online and made a connection between the two, I got a 500 Internal Server error when trying to view the site.

Is there any special steps I should follow to install/publish SS site online? Can someone please describe the steps and appoint me to the right direction to fix the problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: did you check the RewriteBase path in your .htaccess file?

Comment: As there is an internal server error, there must be something in the Apache logfile (or whatever webserver you are using), typically ``/var/log/apache2/error.log``. Besides the ``.htaccess`` file, do you have a ``silverstripe-cache``folder? Remove all files from it - if paths are different on your development machine this can lead to errors.

Comment: Hi Schellmax, how do you know all of this? :) Yet you've got it again! Somehow RewriteBase path has been written without me realising it, is it written automatically somehow? Anyhow thanks for your help again, legend! Thank you, S:)

Comment: Hi Xeraa, thanks a lot for your reply. It turned out to be the RewriteBase path in my.htaccess file, I'm not sure why it was directed to a theme name without me touching it. I'm interested in this silverstripe-cache folder you mentioned, cos some of my subdomains' Redirection is '/silverstripe-cache(/|$)' and I can't change Redirection to 'not directed'. Can you give me a bit more details on this? Also how do I access the Apach logfile or/var/log/apache2/error.log? Is it in cpanel? If so, how do I find it after I log into my cpanel account? Sorry you can see I'm still learning. Thanks heaps:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this to close my question. Just in case someone has a similar problem, please see comments above. The answer is to change the RewriteBase path in the .htaccess file. Thank:)

Comment: What value should the RewriteBase path have?

Comment: Hi Shannon, sorry I can't remember how I wrote the RewriteBase any more as this question was asked a year ago for a temparory subdomain, however I do remember the issue was in the .htaccess file, and it is the RewriteBase I had to change. I think I compared the downloaded original SS htaccess file and the one didn't work, and I figured it out with the suggestions above. I hope this helps, but if this doesn't help, you can alway start a new topic identifies your exact issue.